# Facebook Like and Logout

Tags: facebook, logout

I am pretty new to Stackoverflow and coding but I'll try my best to make this question as clear and simple as possible:

I'm looking to create a webpage where I have a Facebook Like button and a Logout button that will sign user out of Facebook account...so user can Facebook Like, enter login info, then Logout. Here the script I have so far but I have refresh in order for logout to work and direct back to main page. Many Thanks for any help:

Interactive link: http://jsfiddle.net/nrdnx/11/

Code:

```
<html>
    <head>
      <title>My Great Web page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>

<script>
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : '271358172932770', // App ID
      status     : true, // check login status
      cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
      xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
    });

    // Additional initialization code here
    getStatus();
  };

  // Load the SDK Asynchronously
  (function(d){
     var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
     ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
   }(document));


</script>



</script>

       <iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=www.facebook.com/orangeleaflawrence"
        scrolling="no" frameborder="0"
        style="border:none; width:450px; height:80px"></iframe>

<a href="javascript:void();" onclick="getStatus()">Get Status</a>


<div id="logout"><a href="logout.html">Logout of Facebook</a></div>


<script>

FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', function(response) {
  alert('The status of the session is: ' + response.status);
});




function getStatus(){

FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
  alert(response.status);
  if (response.status === 'connected') {

      document.getElementById('logout').style.display='';
    // the user is logged in and has authenticated your
    // app, and response.authResponse supplies
    // the user's ID, a valid access token, a signed
    // request, and the time the access token 
    // and signed request each expire
  } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
    document.getElementById('logout').style.display='none';
    // the user is logged in to Facebook, 
    // but has not authenticated your app
  } else {

    // the user isn't logged in to Facebook.
       document.getElementById('logout').style.display='none';
  }
 }
);

}






</script>


</body>
 </html>
```

​

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I'm quite getting what your problem is, but the logout sdk function is here :
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.logout/